# Deployment workflow to release npm packages

Tags: npm, deployment, workflow

My company has a private package that they release on a weekly basis. Right now our process is quite manual and looks like so:

Code on feature branch -> Manual npm version bump -> Reviews on Github (X approvals required) -> CI runs tests -> OK -> Merge to master -> CI deploys.

However, the manual npm version update is quite cumbersome as it can get out of sync when many PRs are open, and when all reviews are approved, when bumping up the version we need to re-approve the PR.

My question would be, is there a way to get the CI to bump that version, knowing that it also needs to be set on git as a tag version?
Or maybe, is there a simpler way to go about releasing packages?

Thanks